# Exact relative position between two links

Tags: ros, joint, urdf, position

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I'll be blunt...

I used LDD and lxf2urdf to build a robot and I want to change the parent of some of the links because I need certain parts to be independent of the rest of the robot (e.g. the back wheel) if I intend to make some of the joints continuous.

I tried using rviz to select the links and see their relative position, but I found that those numbers aren't precise enough. So how do I know the relative position between two links with the maximum possible precision?

I didn't find any questions regarding this, excuse me if I just couldn't find them! :(

Update:

For example, let's take a random joint from my .urdf file:

```
<joint name="ref_70_joint" type="fixed">
  <parent link="ref_58_link_hub"/>
  <child link="ref_60_link"/>
  <origin xyz="-0.0135999953902 6.27180865763e-08 0.00020025516928" rpy="3.14159265343 1.5396542947e-05 -1.04458704296e-05" />
  <axis xyz="0 0 0" />
</joint>
```

Now let's see what rosrun tf tf_echo /ref_58_link_hub /ref_60_link returns:

```
At time 1332949971.511
- Translation: [0.014, 0.000, -0.000]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, -0.000, 1.000, -0.000]
            in RPY [-3.142, -0.000, -0.000]
```

As you can see I only get three decimal digits, just like rviz.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30621/exact-relative-position-between-two-links/) by [Capelare](https://answers.ros.org/users/967/capelare/) on ROS Answers with karma: 202 on 2012-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've got a better idea. Just write a simple node that uses a TransformListener and print out that information directly. Ideally, someone would write a patch for tf_echo so that precision can be specified...

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('package_name')
import rospy
import tf

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('tf_a')
    listener = tf.TransformListener()

    rate = rospy.Rate(10.0)
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    try:
        (trans,rot) = listener.lookupTransform('/ref_58_link_hub', '/ref_60_link', rospy.Time(0))
        print trans, rot
    except (tf.LookupException, tf.ConnectivityException):
        continue

    rate.sleep()
```

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2012-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Capelare](https://answers.ros.org/users/967/capelare/) on 2012-03-28**:
That's a great idea, thx! :)

**Comment by [Reza Ch](https://answers.ros.org/users/1696/reza-ch/) on 2013-03-21**:
What about printing this data in C++. How to write this code in C++ ?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure how precisely you're seeing the relative position of the links in rviz. However, what I would do is use `rosrun tf tf_echo one_frame two_frame` which should give you the numbers with all the available precision, I think .

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2012-03-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Capelare](https://answers.ros.org/users/967/capelare/) on 2012-03-28**:
Thanks for your reply, but I think that doesn't show all the precision either. I'm going to update the question with an example.